# Joint probability of graph degree

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say I have an undirected graph $G$ with $n$ nodes and probability $p$ of an edge between any pair of nodes $i,j$

I'm trying to find the joint probability density function for $2$ nodes whose degrees can be taken as random variables $X,Y$

So I know individually $P(X=x)$ and $P(Y=y)$ are binomial distributions with $n,p$.

But I'm stuck on calculating $P(X = x, Y=y)$ so the probability that one node is degree $x$ and another node is degree $y$

I don't know how to get around the fact that there might be an edge between the $2$ considered nodes and I'm confused about how it affects the density.

Obv if they have no connection, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent so the result in that case is easy.

So I can write $P(x,y) = P(x,y | connected)P(connected) + P(x,y | not connected)P( not connected) $

So if the $2$ nodes are connected, then is $P(x,y | connected) = P (x-1, y-1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the two distinct vertices $v$ and $w$.

There are $n-2$ edges adjacent to $v$ but not $w$; there are $n-2$ edges adjacent to $w$ but not $v$; there is $1$ edge adjacent to both $v$ and $w$.

Do some casework.

- If $x \ge 1$ and $y \ge 1$, then $\{X=x, Y=y\}$ can be broken into two cases.

  1. $x$ and $y$ adjacent: this happens with probability $p \cdot \binom{n-2}{x-1} p^{x-1} (1-p)^{(n-2)-(x-1)} \cdot \binom{n-2}{y-1} p^{y-1} (1-p)^{(n-2)-(y-1)}$
  2. $x$ and $y$ not adjacent: this happens with probability $(1-p) \cdot \binom{n-2}{x} p^{x} (1-p)^{(n-2)-x} \cdot \binom{n-2}{y} p^{y} (1-p)^{(n-2)-y}$ (with the convention that $\binom{a}{b} = 0$ if $a<b$).

There are a few more cases to consider.

Comment: I think in the 2nd part you forgot a factor of (1-p) to account for the probability x,y are not adjacent?

Comment: @Myro Thanks, fixed